# Best way to send an Integer ArrayList as an intent extra?

Tags: java, android, performance

Which is more efficient, sending an ArrayList as an intent extra or converting the ArrayList into and integer array using the toArray() method and then sending that using putIntArrayExtra()?

Ex:

```
Intentname.putIntArrayListExtra(ArrayList);
```

Or:

```
Intentname.putIntArrayExtra(ArrayList.toIntArray());
```

Comment: I doubt that either of these implementations are significantly faster than the other. If you are trying to optimize your application, you should use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). It will show you where your application is taking the most time, which might not even be packing integers into an intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putIntArrayExtra` does not exist - I assume you mean `putExtra(String, int[])`.

Both should have identical run time *when you call the methods*, as they each boil down to the identical line in Bundle.java of the Android source:

```
//mMap is of type ArrayMap - also in the Android source
mMap.put(key, value);
```

That said, "efficiency" as you are requesting is not nearly descriptive enough to give an accurate answer. ArrayList takes up more memory, is slower to serialize and deserialize, has a custom (and non-constant-time...but more accurate!) `hashcode()` implementation, etc.

But, ultimately it depends what you're doing with this array (List or not) before creating this Intent and after you retrieve it on the other side. If possible, keep the data-structure as an int[] to begin with (and therefore never call `toIntArray()` ) unless you need the helper methods/niceties that `ArrayList` provides.

Comment: I disagree with `each ultimately boil down to the the identical line`. This line is only the temporary storage for that variable. It is latter serialized for to be transmitted to the received of the intent. What it really boils down to is the writeToParcel of the bundle, which in turn leads to `Parcel.writeValue`. `int[]` goes to `writeIntArray`, while `List` goes to write list, and then to `writeInt`. In the end, there is a significant overhead to use `List`, as each value is prefixed by the type of value, resulting in ~twice more values being serialized.

Comment: Hence why I said immediately before that, "identical run time when you call the methods" and then followed up with the caveats of using an ArrayList - including the serialization.

Comment: agreed with your subsequent analysis, but I think it is misleading to emphasize the `putExtra` call.